# Determine optimization level in preprocessor?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, compiler-optimization, c-preprocessor

`-Og` is a relatively new optimization option that is intended to improve the debugging experience while apply optimizations. If a user selects `-Og`, then I'd like my source files to activate alternate code paths to enhance the debugging experience. GCC offers the [`__OPTIMIZE__` preprocessor macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros), but its only set to 1 when optimizations are in effect.

Is there a way to learn the optimization level, like `-O1`, `-O3` or `-Og`, for use with the preprocessor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is not possible to know directly the optimization level used to compile the software as this is not in [the list of defined preprocessor symbols](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

You could rely on `-DNDEBUG` (no debug) which is used to disable assertions in release code and enable your "debug" code path in this case.

However, I believe a better thing to do is having a system wide set of symbols local to your project and let the user choose what to use explicitly.:

- `MYPROJECT_DNDEBUG`
- `MYPROJECT_OPTIMIZE`
- `MYPROJECT_OPTIMIZE_AGGRESSIVELY`

This makes debugging or the differences of behavior between release/debug much easier as you can incrementally turn on/off the different behaviors.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I did not think it was available. If someone figures out a clever (or obvious) hack, I might revisit the accepted answer.

Comment: `glibc`'s headers (in particular, `/usr/include/features.h`) look for the `__OPTIMIZE__` flag when `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` is set.

Also, `__OPTIMIZE__` now appears in the [list of symbols](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) linked to above.

Answer (score 26):

I don't know if this is clever hack, but it is a hack.

```
$ gcc -Xpreprocessor -dM -E - < /dev/null > 1
$ gcc -Xpreprocessor -dM -O -E - < /dev/null > 2
$ diff 1 2
53a54
> #define __OPTIMIZE__ 1
68a70
> #define _FORTIFY_SOURCE 2
154d155
< #define __NO_INLINE__ 1
```

clang didn't produce the FORTIFY one.

Comment: Very good idea... "just see for yourself!"... I wouldn't have thought of it. That's not a hack, that's investigation!

Comment: One-liner: `diff <(gcc -Xpreprocessor -dM -E - < /dev/null) <(gcc -Xpreprocessor -dM -O -E - < /dev/null)`

Answer (score 1):

Some system-specific preprocessor macros exist, depending on your target. For example, the Microchip-specific XC16 variant of gcc (currently based on gcc 4.5.1) has the preprocessor macro `__OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL__`, which takes on values 0, 1, 2, s, or 3.

Note that overriding optimization for a specific routine, e.g. with `__attribute__((optimize(0)))`, does not change the value of `__OPTIMIZE__` or `__OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL__` within that routine.