# Get options used for compilation with preprocessor directives

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to get flags used for compilation/linking with preprocessor directives?

Like if a program is compiled with gcc -O3 helloworld.c
Can I get a macro that gives "-O3 helloworld.c" or at least "-O3" ?

Can I do that with intel's c compiler as well?

Thank you.

[Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh) points me to the __ OPTIMIZE __ macro, which is either 1 or not defined for gcc. If the program is compiled with gcc using any optimization level, __ OPTIMIZE __ will be defined. see [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

Comment: To "get" in which context?

Comment: in the context of source code of a c program. Like later I can #define COMPILER_FLAG __ MAGIC __    Then void main(void) {\ printf("%s",COMPILER_FLAG);\ }

Comment: Check [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html). Specifically `__OPTIMIZE__` and friends.

Comment: You type gcc once, but there are 4 independent operations: preprocessing, compiling, assembling and linking. You can preprocess once and compile many times with different flags.

Comment: it can't be done, at least for gcc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718637/determine-optimization-level-in-preprocessor